# Saving and getting information from Titanium MapView Annotation

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I have the following code that creates a new annotation on my .js:

```
    //Create annotation
    var new_annotation = Titanium.Map.createAnnotation({
        latitude:10,
        longitude:30,
        title:"Title",
        pincolor:Titanium.Map.ANNOTATION_RED,
        customdata:"My custom data",
        animate:true,
        rightButton: Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.DISCLOSURE,
        myid:1
});

$.mapview.addAnnotation(new_annotation);
```

All information like title, latitude and longitude is available on my click function:

```
function doClick(evt){
    alert("title: " + evt.title);
    alert("customdata: " + evt.customdata);
};
```

However customdata is "undefined".

How can save and retrieve data from a Titanium MapView Annotation? Why the data is "undefined"?

Comment: Is this on iOS or android? The click functionality differs for map annotations between platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding your `customdata` object to the annotation itself, the `evt` object that is passed into the `click` event listener [is defined in the DOCS](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Map.Annotation-event-click) as passing the title of the annotation explicitly, so of course you can retrive it, but to get the `customdata` you have to do this:

```
function doClick(evt){
    alert("title: " + evt.title);
    // Get the annotation, then get the custom data attached to it
    alert("customdata: " + evt.annotation.customdata);
};
```

Comment: The suggestion didn't appear on the Ctrl+Space tooltip so I never imagined it would be that simple! Many thanks!